# Has Many through relationship laravel didnot solve

Tags: laravel, performance, polymorphism, has-many-through

I Have

```
Worker -> HasOne-> Document ->morphMany ->FIles
                 ->HasOne-> Medical ->morphMany ->FIles
                ->HasOne-> Course ->morphMany ->FIles
```

I want to use hasManyTrough to get files data from worker, I defined

```
public function medical_detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne(MedicalDetail::class);
}
```

Tried this :

```
public function document_files()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(File::class, Document::class);
}
```

In worker but It expects document_id, how can I use ir for polymirhic relationship?

Also did this

```
public function document_files()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        File::class,
        Document::class,
        'worker_id',
        'filable_id',
        'id', 
        'id' 
    );
}
```

THese are my models

File model

```
    protected $fillable = ['file_type', 'file_name', 'fiable_id', 'filable_type'];

    public function filable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Worker MOdel

```
    public function course()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Course::class);
    }

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Document::class);
    }
```

Document model

```
   protected $fillable = ['doc_name', 'worker_id'];
    public function worker()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Worker::class);
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'filable');
    }
```

This is one alternative I added, but gives me `No query results for model [App\\Models\\Worker] 1`  . SInce files table has         `$table->morphs('filable');` This defined so I added filable_id. These are my models: docuemnt,file

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide at least one use case (working code) where these relations are used and caused problem.

Comment: In file model check spellings of fillable. Your are using  **filable_id** in relationship but in file model it **fiable_id**.